# Read contents of a file into string while skipping first two lines

Tags: c, io

I'm trying to read the contents of a file into one string without reading in the first two lines.

Right now I have:

```
char* LoadDocument(char* name) {
    char* buffer = 0;
    long length;
    FILE* f = fopen(name, "r");
    if(f) {
      fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
      length = ftell(f);
      fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
      buffer = malloc(length);
      if (buffer) {
        fgets (buffer, 100, f);
      }
      fclose (f);
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

But I'm not sure how to skip the first two lines. Also, it appears my malloc is insufficient to hold the whole file here, because it's not getting the whole file.

Comment: You don't get the full file in `buffer` because you only read *at most* `100` bytes, of until the first newline (whichever is first). Also remember that `fgets` terminates the buffer *as a string*, and so you need to allocate one extra character for the terminator.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to [read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) the complete file into the buffer, manually find the end of the second line, and [move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memmove) the remaining data to the beginning of the buffer.

Also, don't forget to add the string terminator, if you want to use the buffer as a string.

Comment: How about opening the file in binary mode and skipping 2 newline characters and copying the rest?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to read two lines before your "real" reading begins:

```
char line[1024];

fgets(line, sizeof line, f);
fgets(line, sizeof line, f);
```

You should probably error-check this too, since the file might be shorter in which case you won't get the expected results. Also the length might be too short. If you really want to support any length, read single characters until you find the end of line, twice.

Your final `fgets()` should probably be a `fread()` call, to read the entire rest of the file. You might want to compensate for the lost `length` due to the initial skipping, too.